# What was the communication protocol used on board the Apollo moon lander?

Tags: usb, uart, serial, rs232, serial-bus

It seems that the development of [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) was contemporary ~1961 the maiden moon landing of the Apollo vehicle, while the development of one of the oldest digital signalling standards [RS232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#History) using the [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter#History) hardware was crystallized later, and that of the advent of the [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#History) hardware, transmission standard and related communication protocols occurred much later.

> What was the communication protocol used on the controllers and processers on board the Apollo lander vehicle?

Comment: RS232 isn’t a protocol.

Comment: @Kartman thanks for bringing the error to my attention. I have edited the text of the question to remove it.

Comment: Which protocol? The telemetry via radio or for the internal systems. I’d guess the internal systems were hard wired - switches and lamps for the most part.

Comment: “My favorite programming language is solder” -- Bob Pease

Comment: @Kartman the question is concerned with the internal systems including the controllers and processors including the CPU.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with the tags you've assigned it.

Comment: @kb314 then there's none. There are no independent "communicating" components, just a monolithic computer and a lot of discretes (switches, lights, motors, analog sensors).

Comment: The Apollo moon landing was in 1969. RS232 dates to 1960.

Comment: @hobbs wouldn't it be a good guess that controllers and for the various modules such as the orientation, propulsion, attitude controller etc. were independent peripherals feeding to and fro to the CPU?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I realize that, but I'm still unsure that RS232 was indeed used.

Comment: @hobbs your comment seems as likely to me as an independently developed system. Is it fair to say that in the absence of series communication a lot of extra wiring would be necessitated alongside higher redundancy requirements for robustness?

Comment: The Bell 103 modem, using rs232 came out in 1962. Early ASR33 teletypewriters used current loop (with UART style signals, which were electromechanically generated), but later ones used rs232. Not sure when that started. Perhaps when the Bell 103 modem came out, as the original use for rs232 was connecting teletype and modems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encoding of characters into digital data streams is rather older than Apollo. Émile [Baudot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code)'s system was patented in 1874, about the time when Jules Verne was writing of the US sending a ship to the moon in the immediate postbellum period.

The [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_S-band) communication system used for the Apollo mission integrated a bunch of different data and analog streams. Digital commands were encoded with many extra bits so that errors would be detected with a probability of erroneous decoding of \$ \lt 10^{-9}\$. Redundancy and fail-over modes of operation were strong concerns.

Here, for example, from [this](https://www.honeysucklecreek.net/images/pdfs/SP-87.pdf) document is the LEM (Lunar Excursion Module) down link summary:

[image]

Terrestrial communication (to remote base stations) used Western Electric 2400 baud modems.

There is quite a bit of fascinating information in that overview document, including a brief description of the console displays which used special data display CRTs with both magnetic and electrostatic deflection (the latter for vector character generation).

Comment: USB (Unified S-band) FTW!

Comment: @hacktastical  Thanks for that!  I was starting to laugh uncontrollaby.

Answer (score 4):

Dig in here: ftp://ssh.esac.esa.int/pub/ekuulker/Apollo15/The-Apollo-Guidance-Computer-Architecture-and-Operation.pdf

And here: https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/01/a-deep-dive-into-the-apollo-guidance-computer-and-the-hack-that-saved-apollo-14/3/

tl; dr: a bespoke binary stream format for telemetry uplink and downlink.

Comment: Thanks for both the links. They read a fascinating story.